# Next js — How fetch some global site data to redux in _app.js?

Tags: redux, next.js

I'm using next js with redux thunk.
And I want to fetch some global site data and save it to redux storage, so I could use it later in components.

The only way I can do it now - is to call action to fetch this globalData in every page in getInitialProps, But there are a lot of pages.

Is it possible to make this in **_app.js**, so I wouldn't have to repeat this in every page? What is correct way to do it?

P.S. Everything is easy with client side. The problem is about Server Side!
**I need server to fetch data and put it to redux storage!** And I need to do it for **any page of site.** (I don't care about what will happen next on client side)

Comment: I think you are going the wrong way. You are trying to fetch data on the server in `getInitialProps` and cache in on the client with redux storage. Obviously, it will not be possible to check on the server if data was loaded previously.

Comment: You need to fetch data in the `componentDidMount` method if you want to cache it on the client side.

Comment: First of all I need to do fetch in every pages. And I want go do it both on client side and on server side.
Of course I can include this fetch in every page of my site... But there are a lot of pages.. and it's a little dummy to copy the same code to every page of site!

Comment: Take a look at `next-redux-wrapper`. It's a HOC for app.js that injects store into the getInitialProps context.

https://github.com/kirill-konshin/next-redux-wrapper